# Dynamic views for categories

Tags: views

I'm really stuck on a problem that I'm seeking assistance on.
I have 3 categories under the same Taxonomy Vocab for a specific content type .

Taxonomy:
 - category 1
 - category 2
 - category 3

Now I need to make a view that when i click the link for category 1 it will show all content under that category . same as the other category . Im currently using D7.

I thank you much in advance for any assistance you can provide!

this is a follow up question ...

contextual filter saves me from this filter but when I try to access it in the url the layout of the page is not like the views ... it gets the views for the taxonomy

Comment: Would it not work to use the pages taxonomy makes available for you, i.e. /taxonomy/term/%tid?

Comment: I personally always use Display suite + https://www.drupal.org/project/views_content_ds

Answer (score 0):

Suppose u have a content type called as Article. So simply add the fields in the view that you wish to show.

After adding the required fields add a contextual filter for the taxonomy term (Content: Has taxonomy term ID). In the contextual filter, select provide default values "Taxonomy term id from the url".

Save the view and it would serve your purpose.

Comment: sorry but I can't see the  "taxonomy term id from the url" in the contextual filter for the taxonomy term (Content: has taxonomy term ID).

Answer (score 0):

The [Taxonomy Views Integrator](https://www.drupal.org/project/tvi) module  will help you.

> The TVI (Taxonomy Views Integrator) module allows selective overriding of taxonomy terms and/or vocabulary with the view of your choice. Using TVI you can easily create custom views to output all terms in X vocabuarly.

Install this and change tid accordingly.